# error during xml parsing - Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to use `XML::Tidy` in other to indent a `XML` file:

```
sub reformatXML {
    #
    # the only argument to this function is the file name
    #
    my $file = $_[ 0 ];
    #
    # create a new XML::Tidy object from $file
    #
    my $tidy = XML::Tidy->new( 'filename' => $file );
    #
    # Tidy up the indenting
    #
    $tidy->tidy();
    #
    # write out changes back to the file
    #
    $tidy->write();
    print "$file was reformated.\n";
    return
}

sub main(){
    #
    # get the current directory in which is the 
    # program running on
    #
    #my $current_dir = getcwd;
    #iterateDir( $current_dir );
    my $file = "/path/to/xml/file/autotest.xml";
    reformatXML( $file );
}
```

As simple as that. However, when I call my `main()` function I get:

```
501 Protocol scheme 'd' is not supported d:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_buildA/src/build/kits/tc.dtd
Handler couldn't resolve external entity at line 2, column 29, byte 73
error in processing external entity reference at line 2, column 29, byte 73:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE kit SYSTEM "tc.dtd">
============================^
<kit>
  <contact/>
 at C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187
```

I'm new to `Perl`, and I have not idea why is that error. Could someone please help me figuring it out?

The head of the `XML` file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE kit SYSTEM "tc.dtd">
<kit>
  <contact/>
  <description>autotest files</description>
  <history>
    <hist>06-May-2005                  Created</hist>
    <hist>17-Jun-2005            Add autotest.jar to rtkit</hist>
    <hist>29-Jun-2005            Remove bits picked up elsewhere</
hist>
    <hist>15-Jul-2005            Added acad_add_note_types.</hist>
    <hist>20-Sep-2005            Add ai stuff</hist>
    <hist>31-Oct-2005            DMS BnT fixes</hist>
    <hist>03-Nov-2005            Pander to kitting's obsession abo
ut unique filenames</hist>
    <hist>17-Nov-2005            Add ics schema and junit</hist>
    <hist>09-Dec-2005            add gdt_autotest</hist>
    <hist>11-Jan-2006            Merge in P10.0.1.5</hist>
    <hist>16-Jan-2006      Merge</hist>
    <hist>26-Jan-2006      Need inclass.plmxml to pass tceng
_util autotest</hist>
    <hist>06-Mar-2006      Add qdiff.pl</hist>
    <hist>09-Mar-2006      Kernel tests need a couple fms cl
ient files</hist>
    <hist>10-Mar-2006      Missing dependent library</hist>
    <hist>19-Jan-2006      Merged from timb_gmo</hist>
    <hist>17-Jan-2006      GMO Kernel Autotests Implementati
```

Comment: Looks like there is an error in your DTD file and the parser is freaking out.

Comment: @scrappedcola I know and that sucks a lot but why is the parser caring about the DTD file? it's just supposed to parse them correctly.

Comment: If you remove your DTD declaration does it parse? There might be an error in you XML somewhere else.

Comment: This posting might help you: http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-xml/8554/

Comment: @scrappedcola Those `DTD` declarations are in all the `xml` files, and they are used in the kitting process, so I can't just remove.

Comment: @scrappedcola I'm not using `XML::XPath`, I'm using `XML::Tidy` instead... (although `XML::Tidy` probably uses `XML::XPath`

Comment: It does use `XML::XPath`

Comment: @toolic Have you seen this problem before? I don't know what is trying to resolve `DTD` when it's supposed only to indent the file correctly.

Comment: @philippe: No, but I can produce a similar problem with your XML snippet and `XML::Tidy`.  I am on unix and I can use `xmllint` to read and tidy your XML snippet.

Comment: @scrappedcola I don't need to validade the doc, just indent it correctly is what I want.

Comment: The HTML tidy has an ignore method you might see if XML Tidy has the same. in HTML it is $tidy->ignore(text=> qr/DOCTYPE/);

Answer (score 2):

XML::Tidy (or rather, one of the modules it uses) appears to expect an absolute path to a file be a valid URL, and it's not. It think the URL specified is

```
 d:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_buildA/src/build/kits/tc.dtd
```

when it's really

```
 file:///d:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_buildA/src/build/kits/tc.dtd
```

I don't know how to work around that bug. You could try changing

```
my $file = "...";
reformatXML($file);
```

to

```
my $file = "...";
my $url = URI::file->new($file);
reformatXML($url);
```

---

That's the immediate bug. Beyond that, there's the issue that a relative URL is provided to the DTD. That's not necessarily wrong, but it is a bit odd. It means that `tc.dtd` must be present in the same directory as `autotest.xml`. Is that truly the case?

---

Some parsers (e.g. XML::LibXML) have an option to avoid fetching DTDs. It's usually unnecessary and thus a waste of time, money, CPU and bandwidth. Look for such an option. It would probably be in the constructor of one of the classes inherited by XML::Tidy.

Comment: shouldn't that d-pipe e.g. file://d|/UDU...   ?

Comment: @Len Jaffe, "|" is acceptable too (although your url is missing a slash), but it was a hack for back when urls accidentally didn't allow ":" in the path. ":" is preferred. See [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: Ikegami, when I applied your suggestions, I got: `Cannot open file 'file:///D:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_buildA/src/build/kits/kit_web.xml' at C:/xampp/perl/site/lib/XML/XPath.pm line 53.
`

Comment: I did do:
`my $file = "D:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_buildA/src/build/kits/kit_web.xml";
 my $url = URI::file->new( $file );
 reformatXML( $url );`

Comment: Ikegami, also for your question, `tc.dtd` must be present in the same directory as `autotest.xml`. That's a decision that whomever wrote that xml file decided to take

Comment: I asked (rhetorically) if it was truly the case the `tc.dtd` is in the same directory as `autotest.xml`. Your reply doesn't seem related.